# How to convert grop of sentences into html list using autohotkey

Tags: windows-xp, html, autohotkey, productivity

for example if 4 sentences like this then

```
Sem ullamcorper amet, dictumst sollicitudin

Erat duis vel, totam eu, amet justo. Sed corporis 

In mauris odio. Penatibus pede. Mollis in. Quis 

Id lacinia in, dui felis. Interdum at, mi velit
```

after select all text and pressing AHK key it should be result.

```
<ul>
    <li>Sem ullamcorper amet, dictumst sollicitudin</li>

    <li>Erat duis vel, totam eu, amet justo. Sed corporis</li>

    <li>In mauris odio. Penatibus pede. Mollis in. Quis</li> 

    <li>Id lacinia in, dui felis. Interdum at, mi velit</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd be curious on how many questions you ask each day!

Comment: @r0ca Should i not ask questions

Comment: This is not my point.

Comment: @r0ca; Are those of us who wish to increase our knowledge any less worthy than those who share it? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer here http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic20808.html&highlight=css